# Delete folders and contents with many specific dir names from all sub folders with powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, subdirectory

I am using win 10 and Power Shell V5.1.18362.1110

I have hundreds of duplicate named sub directories in multiple sub directories under one directory I need to delete the specific directories and their contents and going through each of them by hand is very time consuming. It would be great if it could reference a text file I could type up that might have them listed one line at a time. (or whatever you suggest).

I have tried:

```
$source="h:\Batch Remove TEST" #location of directory to search
$strings=@("1306001", "1311001")

cd ($source); get-childitem -Include ($strings) -Recurse -force | Remove-Item -Force –Recurse
```

It will remove the two folders from the first sub directory but not the subsequent sub dirs.

It returned this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At H:\Batch Remove TEST\cm.ps1:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem . -Include 1306001,1311001 -Recurse -Force | Remove-Ite ...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem],UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I am stumped.
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you can't delete the powershell file you currently have open

Comment: The directories and their files are below the powershell file directory. It works great on the first sub directory then stops before checking before the next sub directory. I need it to check all sub directories under the powershell file, remove the directories and files stated in $strings,  not just the first sub directory. Thank you!